# Grant privileges to users that who can select, delete, update, insert in which table with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, permissions

I'm developing an app(WCF Restful) that has 400 users and I want to grant privileges to users that who can select, delete, update, insert in which table.

My question is, how can I implement this feature?

My data access layer implemented with EF and I have a table 'User' that store the users.

I've found these ways:

1. SQL Server User Privileges (each user connect to DB with custom connection string)
2. Add a filter to all query entity framework that it checks user access

Which one is better?

Comment: Definitely the former. Do it once, not every time you create or update a procedure.

Comment: The admin of application want to decide who user can have access to table (it’s a dynamic approach).